# Why does this range query returns empty results?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am querying an elasticsearch (2.0) cluster and would like to get events with a timestamp older than a specific one (30 August 2015 in the case below):

```
POST /constant_scan/vulnerability/_search
{
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "filter":{
            "range":{
               "HOST_START_iso":{
                  "lt":"2015-08-30"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This search returns

```
{
   "took": 44,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

The DB has relevant records. A query for all elements returns, among others, an entry with a timestamp on August 20 (older than August 30)

```
{
   "took": 241,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 58517,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "scan_constant",
            "_type": "vulnerability",
            "_id": "10.89.0.103",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "private": true,
               "authenticated": false,
               "HOST_START_iso": "2015-08-20T10:19:24+00:00"
            }
         },
         (...)
```

I tried to use a full ISO date as the delimiter, tried `lte` instead of `lt` - same results. Searching for events newer that the date yields the same (there are events on both sides of that date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're querying the `constant_scan` index

```
POST /constant_scan/vulnerability/_search
```

while your documents are stored in the `scan_constant` index (according to the sample document you provided)

Try POSTing your query to this URL instead:

```
POST /scan_constant/vulnerability/_search
```

Comment: Thank you - I will leave my question as a milestone of brainlessery (and accept in 9 minutes)

Comment: No worries, there are no dumb questions!